# Determine Whether The Equation Is Linear In $x_1, x_2, $ And $x_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine Whether The Equation Is Linear In $x_1, x_2, $ And $x_3$

According to the book I'm using, the following are linear equations:

$$x_1 + 5x_2 - \sqrt{2x_3} = 1$$

$$ \pi x_1 - \sqrt{2x_2} + \frac{1}{3}x_3 = 7^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

The book also states:

> a linear equation does not involve any products or roots of variables

What am I missing?

The exercise from the book, Elementary Linear Algebra by Howard Anton/ Chris Rorres:[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the root includes the variable? Maybe it's $\sqrt{2} x_3$?...

Comment: If the root includes the variable, it seems that the answer is obvious.

Comment: The variable is included in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all I know, those equations, as they are written, are nonlinear. What the book states corresponds to my knowledge. It does seem strange that those equations are given as linear. Maybe what the book says is the first one is linear in $x_1,x_2$ but not $x_3$ and the second is linear in all variables but $x_2$? That's what I would say. Another possibility is that the root does not include the variable, in both cases. In that case, they would be linear in all variables. Anyway if there is a product, power, root, logarithm or any other function of variables that is not a coefficient times a single variable, the equation is not linear. That, at least, is what I know.

Comment: I added book title and screenshot of the problem to the question.

Comment: I can only restate what I said in the answer, and say with all possible certainty that the solution is WRONG. Write to the authors of the book for an explanation, that is all I can tell you. Maybe it is a typo, and those roots should not include the variables. So until someone more expert (or the book authors) illuminates us on this, we are stuck with «the book is wrong».

Comment: After studying some more linear algebra, I'm certain that's a typo. Cheers, @MickG.

Answer (score 1):

This is the original questions in the book Elementary Linear Algebra written by Howard Anton, $11^{\text{th}}$ edition.

[image]

Apparently the questions you got went something wrong.